# Extend username + password Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

How can I know if a Wireless Range Extender device is compatible with that WI-Fi networks that ask for not just a password for connection but also for a username?

Do that kind of devices exists?

Do these networks have a specific name?

Comment: But in short terms, amplifying a WPA2 Enterprise connection (or 802.11 EAP) with a consumer wireless repeater breaks the security of the network. The username/password are supposed to identify you in the network. If you were connected to the repeater, the network wouldn't know who are you in the network (and for the fact the repeater could be configured as WPA2 Personal/public network).

Comment: Related (external website): https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=317429&view=next&sid=177a5671c19ee837e9430b654a48876d

Comment: So it's called "Enterprise Connection", thank you for this and for the link, I wasn't able to find it. Security is not an issue for me in this case, I don't need to know who connects since it would only be me.